# How to resolve 'reserve exceeded (host) : Out of memory' issue with Netezza database?

Tags: netezza, aginity

How to resolve **'reserve exceeded (host) : Out of memory'** issue with Netezza database?

I try to execute Netezza database table small query using aginity tool and i got **'reserve exceeded (host) : Out of memory'** issue. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It the error triggered by any statement or a particular one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restarted Netezza database engine using below IBM Netezza SSH terminal commands

Stop Neteazza database engine

```
nzstop
```

Start Neteazza database engine

```
nzstart
```

Other option is:
restart Linux Netezza database server.

Comment: Cool - I’m a bit slow at times :)